# Buefy Material Design icons not showing using b-icon component

Tags: vue.js, material-design, buefy, material-design-icons

I'm a first time Buefy user.
When I tried to use the b-icon component,
I was confused when I saw that the icon doesn't show,
instead it just showed an empty block element, as if the icon was there.

I tried using a different icon pack but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the official Buefy documentation doesn't tell you is that you have to install the Material Design package,
then import it in your main.js file.

`npm i @mdi/font`

`import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'`

I'm guessing that for a different icon pack you just need to do the same with the relevant package.